# Solve the system of differential equationss

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Linear Differential Equations. How to solve these equations?

> $$y'+\cos(x)\cdot y=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$$
>
> $$y'+\frac{1-2x}{x^2}\cdot y=1$$

Comment: Just apply the method outlined [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx) (Integrating Factor method). The process is very straightforward, and it works for both of your ODE's.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22).

Answer (score 1):

Method of integrating factor.

$y' + P(x) y  = Q(x)$

Multiply trough by the integrating factor $e^{\int P(x) dx}$

$e^{\int P(x)\ dx}y' + P(x)e^{\int P(x)\ dx}y = Q(x)e^{\int P(x)\ dx}$

The left side will integrate to $e^{\int P(x) \ dx}y$

The right side might take some doing.
Then you will need to multiply trough by the reciprocal of your integrating factor.

Answer (score 0):

hint for the first equation:
solve the homogenous equation $$y'(x)+\cos(x)y(x)=0$$ and a particular solution is given by $$y_p=\sin(x)-1$$
for the second equation write:$$y'(x)+\frac{y(x)}{x^2}-2x^{-1}y(x)=1$$